# Is it possible to search a static loaded JSON list with RxJS?

Tags: rxjs

Hi just wondered if it's possible to search an already existing JSON object/array using [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) ? 
Only seen examples with Ajax requests.
I have the JSON loaded already but would love to use [RxJS](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) to filter it.

Any good examples ? 
Hope it's possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to observe a pre-existing collection. Please see the documentation for `Rx.Observable.from()` for documentation and a set of examples.

https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md

`Rx.Observable.from()` is capable of observing an `Array` or any other iterable object by default, and also provides the option to pass in a mapper to convert more complex objects into the sequence you would like to observe.